# Spring XD - Unable to undeploy & destroy stream through --cmdfile option

Tags: spring-data, spring-xd

Today i have started automating certain Spring-XD tasks like, stream creation, deployment, and undeploying the same.

For this, all my undeploy and destroy commands sit in one file, but when i run the following

```
$xd-shell --cmdfile auto_cleanup_14032016_235706.txt
```

I'm getting the following output:

> WARNING: Command 'stream destroy --name ingestion_14032016_235706_<>' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)

But When i run the same command inside the interactive shell xd-shell -- It seems to work fine. :(

Comment: What version of Spring XD? What operating system? What does your file contain? - it looks like it's a command in the file that's bad. I just tested with 1.3.0 and 1.3.1 on OS X with no problems.

Comment: Ok, so i forgot to add the following line at the top of the file . Thanks anyways.

 admin config server --username xdadmin --password devadmin

Answer (score 1):

You will notice this Warning when xd-shell fails to connect to Spring XD admin. Unless specified xd-shell assumes the admin server to be on localhost.
Add below statement to the top of your cmdfile.

> admin config server http://spring-xd-admin-server:9393

Also provide the credentials to spring xd admin if required.